# Cannot use monitor with 2560x1440 resolution 16.04

Tags: intel, nvidia-geforce

I have dell inspiron 17 7000 series with intel i7-7500u and GeForce 940MX and I can't get my external monitor to work with 2560x1440 resolution. Max I can select is 1920x1200.
Ubuntu 16.04
The same pc and monitor works fine on windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set it through "`nvidia x server settings`" not via display settings.

Also check if external monitor support this resolution over connected/chosen port.
(For example some monitors allows only 1080p over HDMI)